# Snap Kit Login Kit Error (Swift)

Tags: swift, snapchat, swift-dictionary

Copying the documentation gets me a "Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members. The error happens on the "let data = " line. If I force unwrap resources, then the error moves to the next line

```
let graphQLQuery = "{me{displayName, bitmoji{avatar}, externalId}}"
    let variables = ["page": "bitmoji"]

    SCSDKLoginClient.fetchUserData(withQuery: graphQLQuery, variables: variables, success: { (resources: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
        let data = resources["data"] //error here
        let me = data["me"]
        let displayName = me["displayName"]
        let bitmoji = me["bitmoji"]
        let bitmojiAvatarUrl = bitmoji["avatar"]
    }, failure: { (error: Error?, isUserLoggedOut: Bool) in
        // handle error
    })
```

If I unwrap data resources and data, then the error moves to the line where I try to set me = data["me"] (error = "Type Any has no subscript members"). Then if I try to unwrap me, the error remains.

ex:

```
let graphQLQuery = "{me{displayName, bitmoji{avatar}, externalId}}"

let variables = ["page": "bitmoji"]

        SCSDKLoginClient.fetchUserData(withQuery: graphQLQuery, variables: variables, success: { (resources: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
            guard let response = resources else { return }
            guard let data = response["data"] else { return }
            print(data)
            let me = data["me"] // error here
            let displayName = me["displayName"]
            let bitmoji = me["bitmoji"]
            let bitmojiAvatarUrl = bitmoji["avatar"]
        }, failure: { (error: Error?, isUserLoggedOut: Bool) in
            // handle error
        })
```

Printing out data returns:

```
{
    me =     {
        bitmoji =         {
            avatar = "{URL}";
        };
        displayName = "{NAME}";
        externalId = "{ID}";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `[AnyHashable: Any]?` is `optional` thats why it's giving an error

> "Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members

So for that you need to wrap it with `if let` condition as shown below:

```
if let response = resources {
    let data = response["data"] //then cast your objects here
}
```

Or you can use `guard let` for that:

```
guard let response = resources else { return }
```

after that you can use `response` object.

Comment: All this does is push the error down the line. if I use guard let to unwrap resources and then unwrap data, I get the error "Type Any has no subscript members" where I try to set me = data["me"] and the error remains if I try to use guard let on me. If I print(data), the result is structured like: {
    me =     {
        bitmoji =         {
            avatar = "https://sdk.bitmoji.com/render/panel/c1d5026-...

Comment: Edited question to reflect trying to unwrap